# Can path integral paths go backwards in time?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, antimatter

The paths can cross any coordinate at any time in the whole space (e.g. Universe space). Integration goes over all could-you-imagine paths. But time goes strictly forward. Can time variable resemble coordinate variable and path be able to expect backward turn?

Upd 2014-01-04: yes, it's called spacetime, but the time coordinate is still very special.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean. If you are asking whether it is possible to construct the path integral representation for the time evolution operator that goes back in time, namely the inverse of the usual time evolution operator, then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the path integral description of the relativistic point particle, then "time" is some parameter along the particle's world-line, and goes strictly forward, but there is no restriction on the $x^0$ component. However, these backward trajectories are very quantum in nature, and contribute to the space-like correlation/entanglement of quantum fields (there is an exponential drop-off of correlation functions directly outside the light-cone). Causality is preserved however because correlation is not the same as communication.

Comment: Can you give an example of such trajectory and how the entanglement of quantum field is actually related to these trajectories?  Moreover, since we're working in Minkowski spacetime lets take a very infinitesimal section of this trajectory whose $x^0$ component actually decreases and suppose this small section be timelike then using Lorentz transformation I can make this section point directly in my $-x^0$ axis which means even for an infinitesimal duration of **my** time some information, particle's position or momentum, was communicated back in time.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01778 - this is also about path integral and entanglement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say yes. You can interpret such parts of a trajectory either as a particle traveling backwards in time or as (simultaneously two particles and) an antiparticle traveling forwards in time.