# Geodesic with decreasing value of time coordinate

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, geodesics, arrow-of-time

Does there exists an example of geodesic for an exotic space-time manifold in which even though the proper time on the geodesic is increasing but still the time coordinate of the geodesic in global metric is decreasing?

Edit: What actually intrigued me here was the answer by @lionelbrits [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92289/can-path-integral-paths-go-backwards-in-time). The argument there was very handwavy for me to understand nor any concrete example was given there.

Moreover what I understand from my knowledge of General relativity such kind of geodesic should not be there because of the issue of time-orientability of the spacetime manifold. Again I haven't studied the idea of orientability using math so here I am the victim of hand-waviness.

Comment: Easy enough, start a geodesic with a four velocity that has a negative "time" component. Works in flat space.

Comment: @mmeent that's kind of trivial because we just time reversed the usual point particle worldline.

Comment: That is why I did not post it as a comment, in the hope of getting a clearer formulated question.

Answer (score 0):

Such paths exist in General Relativity: if you enter the Cauchy horizon of a rotating black hole at the right angle, go into an orbit inside the Cauchy horizon and then exit it again, the sign of dt/dτ becomes negative, and the black hole is now a [white hole](https://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/penrose.html#kerr) in your frame of reference.

The only problem is that on your way out while you exit the inner horizon, you go to future infinity and back in a small amount of proper time, so all the blueshifted light that fell into the black hole until future infinity hits you in that one moment when you exit the horizon. That might be a problem for a material observer, since he might get grilled. Thanks to the fact that the universe is expanding and the background radiation of the universe getting asymptotically smaller with time, the radiation hitting you on your way out wouldn't be infinite though.

There's also a thing called the [Carter time machine](https://books.google.at/books?id=VIaIAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=carter%20time%20machine%20kerr&source=bl&ots=urXd4X_VDQ&sig=orcR-BYeFfpSolC63G_BslxsFAo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGssWstozaAhXEzaQKHc43AQIQ6AEIYjAK#v=onepage&q=carter%20time%20machine%20kerr&f=false) near the ring singularity where g<sub>φφ</sub><0 is negative, but in nature the Cauchy horizon is thought to be unstable in the presence of matter, so we don't trust the inner Kerr solution to be physical below the Cauchy horizon. Nevertheless, in theory and under perfect circumstances, the answer to your question would be yes.